# Best way to do a lookup based on ID, I dont want to update the model. I am drawing a blank?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am drawing a blank here..   I am using MVC and my model doesn’t have the Value Name, it just has the ID.

The problem is with ‘itm.DegreeTypeId’ it is just an int. But I need to match it up with a string name..  so  DegreeTypeId 1 = Associates Degree, 2 = Bachelor, 3 = MBA etc.

I don’t want to update the model to have the name, but instead to a quick lookup. What’s the best way to proceed here?  I know I can create a method and have it return the string based on a number but there has to be a better cleaner way.

```
        string education = string.Empty;
        int eduCount = 0;
        foreach (var itm in candidate.Educations)
        {
            if (eduCount > 0) education += "<br><br>";
            education += string.Format("<b>{0}</b><br>{1} {2}<br>{3}Graduated: {4}<br>",
                                      itm.DegreeTypeId,
                                      itm.InstitutionName,
                                      itm.InstitutionLocation,
                                      itm.GraduatedOn.HasValue
                                          ? string.Format("{0:MMMM yyyy}", itm.GraduatedOn.Value)
                                          : string.Empty);
            eduCount++;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a Dictionary

```
static readonly Dictionary<int, string> Degrees = new Dictionary<int, string>() {
    {1, "Associates Degree"},
    {2, "Bachelor"},
    {3, "MBA"},
    ...
};
```

So the relevant snippet looks like this:

```
education += string.Format("<b>{0}</b><br>{1} {2}<br>{3}Graduated: {4}<br>",
                                  Degrees(itm.DegreeTypeId),
                                  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you're after, but a `Dictionary<int, string>` could work (or the reverse if you're trying to look things up the other way). Even a `string[]` could be a simple solution for int to string conversion:

```
static readonly string[] DegreeTypeNames = { null, // Unused
    "Associates Degree",
    "Bachelor",
    "MBA"
};
```

That's useful (and performs really well) if you've got a lot of consecutive values, but if they're *not* all consecutive, the dictionary approach would be better.

If you need to *refer* to these IDs in code, you should potentially consider using an enum.